# Changing the state of a toggle in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, jquery

Is it possible to change the state of a toggle function? Like:

myDiv.toggle ... function 1 , function 2

1. I click on the myDiv element, the function 1 executes
2. I click again, function 2
3. I click again, function 1
   BUT
4. Change the state
5. function 1 again
   etc.

But I need to be able to change the state from outside the toggle function.

Comment: Have you tried already some code?

Comment: What? Can you give a pseudo-code example of what you want to achieve, or a better explanation? Your question is a little confusing when it comes to steps 4. and 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a javascript object that uses closure to track it's state and toggle:

```
    var TOGGLER = function() {
      var _state = true;
      var _msg = "function1";

        var function1 = function() {
            _msg = "function1";
        }

        var function2 = function() {
            _msg = "function2";
        }

      return {
        toggle: (function () {
            _state = !_state;

            if (_state) {
                function1();    
            } else {
                function2();
            } 

            return _msg;
        })
       }
     }();
```

Here is a jsfiddle that shows how to use it to toggle based with the following jquery:  http://jsfiddle.net/yjPKH/5/

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#search").click(function() {
         var message = TOGGLER.toggle();
         $("#state").text(message);
     });
 });
```

Comment: This doesn't provide a method to reset the state.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I just defined the _state variable out of the TOGGLER function and now I can change it from other functions too, if that's what you meant.

Comment: That gives you a global variable - it sould be better to export a `reset` method additionally to the `toggle` method and keep the actual state variable inside the closure.

Answer (score 0):

The toggle function is meant for simple use cases. Changing the state externally is not "simple" anymore.

You cannot easily/safely (it's internal so it may change during minor versions) access the state variable of the toggle function easily as it's stored in the internal dataset of the element.

If you really want to do it, you can try this code though:

```
$._data(ELEMENT, "lastToggle" + func.guid, 0);
```

`func` is the function you passed to `.toggle()`, so you need to save this function in a variable. Here's a minimal example: http://jsfiddle.net/xqgrP/

However, since inside the function there's a `var guid = fn.guid || jQuery.guid++` statement, I somehow think that the devs actually meant to use `guid` instead of `func.guid` for the `_data` key - in that case a minor update is very likely to break things. And after the fix you'd have to iterate over the data set to retrieve the correct key as there is no way to access the guid from outside.

Comment: I see. So I think that making a custom toggle via some variable or an empty div with id is simpler.

Comment: To be honest, that looks like you lack basic js knowledge... And why the hell do you use stuff like `document.getElementById` when you have jQuery available?! Actually, you mix it with jQuery functions, so your code **cannot** work at all!

Comment: Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xqgrP/ - but as i said in my answer, do not use it! It accesses internals which are likely to change at some point.

Comment: Oh, I just saw that this was your own attempt to write a toggler... Anyway, learn something about the JS syntax first and then don't abuse classes for state information but use jQuery's `.data()` method

Comment: I usually code in other languages and I haven't used JavaScript/jQuery for like a year, so I apologize for my lack of basic knowledge.